# how can I use event and listener by laravel to handle the booking?

Tags: laravel, events, event-handling, database-migration

I have rooms in hospitals. Each room has beds with numbers. I want to assign beds to patients. How can I handle this in an easy way:

`rooms` migration:

```
Schema::create('rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('name');
     $table->integer('floor');
     $table->text('description');
     $table->timestamps();
});
```

`beds` migration:

```
Schema::create('beds', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('name');
     $table->string('quality');
     $table->string('charge');
     $table->integer('room_id')->unsigned();;
     $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms')
                      ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
     $table->boolean('status');
     $table->timestamps(); 
});
```

`reservations` migration:

```
Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->date('date_in');
     $table->date('date_out');
     $table->boolean('status');
     $table->integer('patient_id')->unsigned();
     $table->foreign('patient_id')->references('id')->on('patients');
     $table->integer('bed_id')->unsigned();
     $table->foreign('bed_id')->references('id')->on('beds');
     $table->timestamps();
});
```

How can I check for available beds? Get the available beds? Be sure the bed is available. How can I use events and listeners to make the whole thing work?

Comment: You should do that in a transaction. Getting the available beds and booking of one them.

Comment: how can I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pluck() retrieve a Collection containing the values of a single column.

Here, it retrieves a Collection of reservation bed_id:

```
$reserved = Reservation::pluck('bed_id)->all();
```

The whereNotIn method verifies that the given column's value is not contained in the given array:

```
$bed_available = Bed::whereNotIn('id' , $reserved)->get();
```

This query gives you all the bed whose id is not available in that collection $reserved , which i think is your requirement .